# How to Make Minecraft Player's looking position be recorded in java

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

I know this title is confusing. I am making a minecraft mod in java. I made an Item that explodes and spawns lightning when you right click. Currently, it explodes and makes lightning at the position of the player. How would I make it explode at the position the player looks? My item class currently looks like this:

```
package com.mod.elliotmod;

import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.entity.effect.EntityLightningBolt;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

public class ItemMyTNT extends Item {

    public ItemMyTNT(String name, int stackSize) {
        GameRegistry.registerItem(this, name);
        setUnlocalizedName(ElliotMod.MODID + "_" + name);
        setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabMisc);
        setMaxStackSize(stackSize);
    }

    public ItemStack onItemRightClick(ItemStack item, World world, EntityPlayer player) {

        world.spawnEntityInWorld(new EntityLightningBolt(world, player.posX, player.posY, player.posZ));
        world.createExplosion(player, player.posX, player.posY, player.posZ, 5.0F, true);

        return item;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is what I now have:

```
package com.mod.elliotmod;

import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.entity.effect.EntityLightningBolt;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

public class ItemMyTNT extends Item {

    public ItemMyTNT(String name, int stackSize) {
        GameRegistry.registerItem(this, name);
        setUnlocalizedName(ElliotMod.MODID + "_" + name);
        setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabMisc);
        setMaxStackSize(stackSize);
    }

    public ItemStack onItemRightClick(ItemStack item, World world, EntityPlayer player) {

        double x = player.getLookVec().xCoord;
        double y = player.getLookVec().yCoord;
        double z = player.getLookVec().zCoord; 

        world.spawnEntityInWorld(new EntityLightningBolt(world, x, y, z));
        world.createExplosion(player, x, y, z, 5.0F, true);

        return item;
    }
}
```

I found this in the Entity Player class. It may help

```
        Vec3 vec3 = new Vec3(((double)this.rand.nextFloat() - 0.5D) * 0.1D, Math.random() * 0.1D + 0.1D, 0.0D);
        vec3 = vec3.rotatePitch(-this.rotationPitch * (float)Math.PI / 180.0F);
        vec3 = vec3.rotateYaw(-this.rotationYaw * (float)Math.PI / 180.0F);
        double d0 = (double)(-this.rand.nextFloat()) * 0.6D - 0.3D;
        Vec3 vec31 = new Vec3(((double)this.rand.nextFloat() - 0.5D) * 0.3D, d0, 0.6D);
        vec31 = vec31.rotatePitch(-this.rotationPitch * (float)Math.PI / 180.0F);
        vec31 = vec31.rotateYaw(-this.rotationYaw * (float)Math.PI / 180.0F);
        vec31 = vec31.addVector(this.posX, this.posY + (double)this.getEyeHeight(), this.posZ);
```

I used this class and my code looks like this, but doesn't work:

```
public ItemStack onItemRightClick(ItemStack item, World world, EntityPlayer player) {
         Random rand = new Random();
         Vec3 vec3 = new Vec3(((double)rand.nextFloat() - 0.5D) * 0.1D, Math.random() * 0.1D + 0.1D, 0.0D);
         vec3 = vec3.rotatePitch(-player.rotationPitch * (float)Math.PI / 180.0F);
         vec3 = vec3.rotateYaw(-player.rotationYaw * (float)Math.PI / 180.0F);
         double d0 = (double)(rand.nextFloat()) * 0.6D - 0.3D;
         Vec3 vec31 = new Vec3(((double)rand.nextFloat() - 0.5D) * 0.3D, d0, 0.6D);
         vec31 = vec31.rotatePitch(-player.rotationPitch * (float)Math.PI / 180.0F);
         vec31 = vec31.rotateYaw(-player.rotationYaw * (float)Math.PI / 180.0F);
         vec31 = vec31.addVector(player.posX, player.posY + (double)player.getEyeHeight(), player.posZ);

        MovingObjectPosition movingobjectposition = world.rayTraceBlocks(vec3, vec31, false, true, false);
        if (movingobjectposition == null) {
            //nothing was under the player's gaze
            return item;
        }
        if (movingobjectposition.typeOfHit == MovingObjectPosition.MovingObjectType.BLOCK) {
            int ix = movingobjectposition.getBlockPos().getX();
            int iy = movingobjectposition.getBlockPos().getY();
            int iz = movingobjectposition.getBlockPos().getZ();
            if (!world.isBlockNormalCube(movingobjectposition.getBlockPos(), true)) {
                --iy;
            }
            world.spawnEntityInWorld(new EntityLightningBolt(world, ix, iy, iz));
        }
        if (movingobjectposition.typeOfHit == MovingObjectPosition.MovingObjectType.ENTITY) {
            double ix = movingobjectposition.hitVec.xCoord;
            double iy = movingobjectposition.hitVec.yCoord;
            double iz = movingobjectposition.hitVec.zCoord;
            world.spawnEntityInWorld(new EntityLightningBolt(world, ix, iy, iz));
        }

        return item;


    }
```

Comment: shouldn't you be using the position of the item?

Comment: I doesn't matter. The player is still holding the item, so it is at the same place. FYI I don't want fixing with my current code I don't want. Please help address with getting the player's looking position

Comment: see : http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/17662-how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-a-block-the-player-is-looking-at/. The first post describes using the `EntityPlayer`'s `getLookVec()`

Comment: That doesn't work with lightning. I see the sky lighting up, but no bolt. What should I do about this?

Comment: Have you tried `world.strikeLightning(player.getLocation());`

Comment: I think you don't understand what I want to do. I want to have the player look somewhere, and that is where lightning strikes, not the player's position

Comment: I changed my code above to what I currently have. That is what is not working

Comment: Okay, I still think you should call `world.strikeLightningEffect(location)`, where location is the Location object representing where the player is looking.

Answer (score 1):

So your first attempt (using the player's position) is half correct but doesn't go where the player is looking.

You correctly identified that you need to use the player's LookVec *but* you improperly implemented it.  An entity's LookVec is a *normalized vector* it is not a position.

So your second attempt is *still* only half-correct (and is spawning the lightning within 1 block of (0,0,0).

So to correct your error, you need to add these two values together:

```
public ItemStack onItemRightClick(ItemStack item, World world, EntityPlayer player) {

    double x = player.posX + player.getLookVec().xCoord;
    double y = player.posY + player.getLookVec().yCoord;
    double z = player.posZ + player.getLookVec().zCoord; 

    world.spawnEntityInWorld(new EntityLightningBolt(world, x, y, z));
    world.createExplosion(player, x, y, z, 5.0F, true);

    return item;
}
```

Only that's still only partially correct, as it doesn't get the block that the player is looking at: it creates the lightning 1 block in front of the player's face (well, their feet actually, we didn't add in the player's eye height either).

The only way to do *that* is to do some raytracing.

Notes:

- the name of world.rayTraceBlocks_do_do may be different depending on your version of Forge.  I pulled this code out of an [old project](https://github.com/Draco18s/Artifacts/blob/master/main/java/com/draco18s/artifacts/network/PacketHandlerServer.java#L129) and will need some massaging.
- vec3: the vector that is the player's eye location
- vec31: the player's gaze direction (per above example)

  ```
  MovingObjectPosition movingobjectposition = world.rayTraceBlocks_do_do(vec3, vec31, false, true, false);
  if (movingobjectposition == null) {
      //nothing was under the player's gaze
      return item;
  }
  if (movingobjectposition.typeOfHit == MovingObjectPosition.MovingObjectType.BLOCK) {
      int ix = movingobjectposition.blockX;
      int iy = movingobjectposition.blockY;
      int iz = movingobjectposition.blockZ;
      if (!world.getBlock(ix, iy, iz).isNormalCube()) {
          --iy;
      }
      //spawn lightning (ix, iy, iz)
  }
  if (movingobjectposition.typeOfHit == MovingObjectPosition.MovingObjectType.ENTITY) {
      double ix = movingobjectposition.hitVec.xCoord;
      double iy = movingobjectposition.hitVec.yCoord;
      double iz = movingobjectposition.hitVec.zCoord;
      //spawn lightning (ix, iy, iz)
  }
  ```

Comment: both `vec3` and `vec31` give an error. What should I do about this? FYI I use 1.8

Comment: @ElliotKing in this case `iy--` and `--iy` are the same, but that is not always the case. You will need to construct `vec3` and `vec31` yourself (I told you what they are). As for `blockX`, look at the `MovingObjectPosition` class, there will be some form of position field, use that. Likely a `BlockPos`. You will probably also have to convert `world.getBlock` to `getBlockState` as well.

Comment: I just figured it out by replacing `movingobjectposition.blockX;` with `movingobjectposition.getBlockPos().getX();`. Do you know if there even is a function that calls the vector? If so, should I be looking in the `EntityPlayer` class

Comment: @ElliotKing you don't need to deconstruct the BlockPos, just use it directly.  As for the vector, look at what object tile the raytrace function uses, that'll tell you what you're looking for (it might be Vec3i, Vec3f, Vec3d)

Comment: In the `EntityPlayer` class I found this I think it might help

Comment: Look at my post

Comment: @ElliotKing That looks like the same math I appropriated 4-5 years ago when I wrote my own lightning stick. That is, the bit I left out of my answer and summarized.

Comment: `this.` -> `player.`  Please sit down and learn basic java, @ElliotKing

Comment: @ElliotKing Go learn Java. Please. I already told you what you needed to do. I can't hand-hold you all the way to the answer, you need to understand the concepts first. I gave you what was needed to answer your question.

Comment: @ElliotKing that's like "step 2" in a Java 101 course right after "hello world". Go learn Java.

Comment: @ElliotKing I did. `this` becomes `player`

Comment: Ok. No errors appear. The lightning or explosion never happen. I posted my code in my post

Comment: What do the booleans in this line of code mean MovingObjectPosition movingobjectposition = world.rayTraceBlocks_do_do(vec3, vec31, false, true, false);

Comment: Also, how did you calculate the vector representing the player's eye location? Mines places the location too low/too high, and I'm not sure why. This is my code   Vec3 eyeVector = player.getPosition(0).addVector(0, player.getEyeHeight(), 0);